# Has the possibility of time travel been proven or demonstrated?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, time-travel, arrow-of-time

This study by [Lesovik et al., 2019](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41598-019-40765-6) seems to claim they have either sent information or an electron back in time. What is the current status of the idea of time travel (at least on the scale of particles) and the evidence that claims to support it?

Comment: Please note that if you think the answers to the duplicate are outdated, the intended procedure is to offer a bounty with the "current answers are outdated" reason instead of duplicating the question.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/466335/have-researchers-managed-to-reverse-time-if-so-what-does-that-mean-for-physi/466424#466424